# Send Email with AWS SES with image attachment - Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email with AWS SES send_raw_email. My email address is verified on AWS. I am not able to figure out how to format my `destinations:`

```
  destinations: [
    to_addresses: ["example@gmail.com"]
    cc_addresses: ["example@gmail.com"]]
```

The above code throws this error `ArgumentError: expected params[:destinations][0] to be a String, got value {:to_addresses=>["example@gmail.com"], :cc_addresses=>["example@gmail.com"]} (class: Hash) instead.`

I am basing my code off of this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SES/Client.html)

In case it's helpful, what I am trying to do is send an email that has attached images to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation for hash-style arguments is:

```
destinations: {
  to_addresses: [ ... ],
  cc_addresses: [ ... ],
}
```

You're declaring `destinations` with `[ ... ]` which means array, and that hash notation inside is invalid.

Comment: This this really work for you? @belshnickleson97  For me it leads to an error anyway: `expected params[:destinations][0] to be a String, got value [:to_addresses, [...]] (class: Array) instead.`  I can't seem to find any documentation in which this is clearly explained

Comment: @raquelhortab There's a difference between `[ a: 1 ]` and `{ a: 1 }`. Note the leading character should be `{` meaning Hash, not `[` meaning Array.